# Trigger on specific cell in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I have a SQL Server database with users. I want to keep one specific user from changing his picture. I don't believe there is a way to make a single cell immutable but is there a way to create a trigger that is called so that whenever this person changes his picture (newpicture.jpg), the UPDATE gets either rolls back or the data value is changed by to the desired value (justin.jpg)?

I'm not a SQL expert but this is what I have so far

```
CREATE TRIGGER justin ON Users
AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT ImagePath from Users WHERE Id = '[justin's id]')
BEGIN
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
RETURN
END;
GO
```

The problem with this is that it just checks if the specific user already has a picture, and then keeps the entire table (and not just that specific user) from updating.

In short, I just want to keep my friend, Justin, from being able to change his current picture, which is of him drinking out of a juice box. Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: This is an after update trigger, you might want to search about "instead of" triggers

Comment: Be careful when you do a rollback inside a trigger. If your calling program has a transaction the count is going to be off and you won't be able to commit or rollback from your application because the transaction will no longer exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to restrict this specific user from having any `ImagePath` value other than a predefined one, then you can simply use a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`:

```
ALTER TABLE Users
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Justin 
   CHECK ( ([UserId] <> 'Justin') OR 
           ([UserId] = 'Justin') AND (ImagePath = '/images/fixedPic.jpg'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Rolling back the whole transaction just update after his update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER justin 
ON Users
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Users
    SET [ImagePath] = '/images/fixedPic.jpg'
    WHERE [UserId] = '[justins id]'
END;
GO
```